# Transaction Level Delayed Durability

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are looking to deploy Transaction Level delayed durability to our databases.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
-----
COMMIT with (DELAYED DURABILITY = ON)
```

Many of our client SQL servers are 2014 so should be fine but we still have some clients using 2010 - problem is we deploy the same code to all clients
If i use transaction level Delayed Durability on audit log writes what will happen to the pre 2014 servers - will they simply ignore it or will they error? I know on 2014 if DD is not turned on it is simply ignored - just not sure how a pre 2014 server will treat the `COMMIT` with (`DELAYED DURABILITY = ON`) 
I know i could do a version check and apply and `IF ELSE` but not sure its necessary
thanks

Comment: You could test by setting the compatibility level of your database to 2010 version.

Comment: Found a 2010 DB and it will not parse the COMMIT with (DELAYED DURABILITY = ON)

Comment: Can i put the COMMIT in some dynamic SQL so that i can run the version check and parse

Comment: I think you'll have to name your transaction in that case. You'll have to experiment with that. When you've found an acceptable solution, you can answer your own question for other people to reference.

Answer (score 0):

i have tried using Dynamic SQL after a version check so that the code can parse but not run on a pre 2014 server (we deploy code to multiple server types and dont want to create a 2010,12,14 versions of the same code)

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR (1000)

SELECT * FROM TBL_TEST_TABLE

SET @SQL = 'BEGIN TRANSACTION'
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
SET @SQL = ''

            INSERT INTO TBL_TEST_TABLE (TEST_COLUMN)
            VALUES (2020)
            SELECT * FROM TBL_TEST_TABLE

DECLARE @SQLVERSION NVARCHAR(128)
SET @SQLVERSION = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('PRODUCTVERSION') AS NVARCHAR)
SET @SQLVERSION = SUBSTRING(@SQLVERSION, 1, CHARINDEX('.', @SQLVERSION) - 1)

    IF @SQLVERSION < 12 
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = 'ROLLBACK'
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
        SET @SQL = ''
    END


    IF @SQLVERSION > 10
    BEGIN

        SET @SQL = 'COMMIT WITH (DELAYED_DURABILITY = ON)'  
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
        SET @SQL = ''
    END 

 SELECT * FROM TBL_TEST_TABLE
```

The Transaction seems to work in that the update is committed but i get the error

Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.
and
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 1, current count = 0.

is this purely because i'm using the dynamic SQL - how come if it errors the data actually commits?